# urlretrieve 503 error while downloading images

Tags: python

I tried downloading image from url using urllib library and my initial code worked fine with most of the websites

```
def download_image(url, file_name):
    full_file_name = file_name + ".jpg"
    full_path = os.path.join(path, full_file_name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
```

But for one website it start giving 403 access forbidden error so i tried

```
def download_image(url, file_name):
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    full_file_name = file_name + ".jpg"
    full_path = os.path.join(path, full_file_name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
```

This is the error now HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable

the url of the image i tested this code on is http://pic.minitoon.net/albums/2819/01-01/01_000.jpg

I checked a few resources but couldn't get any working for this purpose.

I am using python3.6

EDIT:

I tried using requests

```
import requests

img_data = requests.get(image_url).content
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```

It generate an invalid image.jpg file while for other links it is also working fine

EDIT 2:

Tried with PHP

```
$url = "http://pic.minitoon.net/albums/2819/01-01/01_000.jpg";
$img = "img/img.jpg";
file_put_contents($img,file_get_contents($url));
```

It shows the same 503 error

Can someone help me downloading this specific image "http://pic.minitoon.net/albums/2819/01-01/01_000.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

I got around the issue using pillow library and taking screenshot, although not the best solution but works

```
from PIL import Image
driver.get("http://pic.minitoon.net/albums/2819/01-01/01_000.jpg")
image = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(" img")
location = image.location
size = image.size
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")

im = Image.open("screenshot.png")
left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
im.save('screenshot.png')
```

please suggest if there are better ways to do this, since i haven't found a thing that works around this 503 error hence going with this soution for now